# Spring Data RedisTemplate, ttl is not working when setting a value

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

I want to set a ttl for my keys that are stored in Redis, and I have done that in the following way:

```
@Component
public class RedisBetgeniusMarketService implements BetgeniusMarketService {

    private static final int DEFAULT_EVENTS_LIFE_TIME = 240;

    @Value("${redis.events.lifetime}")
    private long eventsLifeTime = DEFAULT_EVENTS_LIFE_TIME;

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, Market> marketTemplate;

    @Override
    public Market findOne(Integer fixtureId, Long marketId) {
        String key = buildKey(fixtureId, marketId);
        return marketTemplate.boundValueOps(key).get();
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Integer fixtureId, Market market) {
        String key = buildKey(fixtureId, market.getId());
        BoundValueOperations<String, Market> boundValueOperations = marketTemplate.boundValueOps(key);
        boundValueOperations.expire(eventsLifeTime, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        boundValueOperations.set(market);
    }

    private String buildKey(Integer fixtureId, Long marketId) {
        return "market:" + fixtureId + ":" + marketId;
    }
}
```

But, when I am printing the ttl of the created key it's equal to `-1`.

**Please, tell me what I am doing wrong.**

The template bean is configured in the following way:

```
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, com.egalacoral.spark.betsync.entity.Market> marketTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final RedisTemplate<String, com.egalacoral.spark.betsync.entity.Market> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(com.egalacoral.spark.betsync.entity.Market.class));
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return redisTemplate;
    }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to call `expire(…)` and `set(…)` in a different order. The [SET](http://redis.io/commands/set) command removes any timeout that was previously applied:

From the documentation at http://redis.io/commands/set:

> Set key to hold the string value. If key already holds a value, it is overwritten, regardless of its type. Any previous time to live associated with the key is discarded on successful SET operation.

In your case you just need to switch the order of `expire(…)` and `set(…)` to `set(…)` and `expire(…)`.

```
@Override
public void save(Integer fixtureId, Market market) {
    String key = buildKey(fixtureId, market.getId());
    BoundValueOperations<String, Market> boundValueOperations = marketTemplate.boundValueOps(key);

    boundValueOperations.set(market);
    boundValueOperations.expire(eventsLifeTime, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

Besides that, you could improve the code by setting the value and expiry in one call. `ValueOperations` (`RedisOperations.opsForValue()`) provides a `set` method that sets the key and timeout with the signature

```
void set(K key, V value, long timeout, TimeUnit unit);
```

Comment: Thanks, for detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this also to expire a Key in Redis for a given specific time

```
redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(key, value, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have replace `set()` and the `expire()` methods and it's start working.

```
@Override
public void save(Integer fixtureId, Market market) {
    String key = buildKey(fixtureId, market.getId());
    BoundValueOperations<String, Market> boundValueOperations 
                                  = marketTemplate.boundValueOps(key);
    boundValueOperations.set(market);
    boundValueOperations.expire(eventsLifeTime, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```